# Why is fread not accepting the skip command?

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I have a .txt dataset where the first 12 lines are text followed by 2 blank rows and then the data

```
DATE           HEIGHT    INPUT     OUTPUT  TESTMEASURE
01/01/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
01/02/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
```

But when I do a

```
dat <- fread('data.txt'),
```

It skips 15 rows, and uses the first data line as column name for the imported dataset. It ignores the header line.

```
01/01/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
```

The skip parameter is not affecting what I import at all. How can I mention the row number which needs to be used as the column name. Alternatively I can rename the column names, but the first line of data shouldn't be ignored.

## DIAGNOSIS

```
Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
File opened, filesize is 0.001319 GB.
Memory mapping ... ok
Detected eol as \r\n (CRLF) in that order, the Windows standard.
Positioned on line 1 after skip or autostart
This line is the autostart and not blank so searching up for the last non-blank ... line 1
Detecting sep ... '\t'
Detected 5 columns. Longest stretch was from line 15 to line 30
Starting data input on line 15 (either column names or first row of data). First 10 characters: 01/01/1933
The line before starting line 15 is non-empty and will be ignored (it has too few or too many items to be column names or data): DATE           HEIGHT    INPUT    OUTPUT  TESTMEASURE the fields on line 15 are character fields. Treating as the column names.
```

Comment: Should it be `dat <- fread('data.txt', skip=15)`?

Comment: @ChiPak I need to skip 12+2=14 lines. But anything below, 15, and the dataset is not affected.

Comment: The first line imported remains 01/02/1933 regardless of what I skip.

Comment: I'm addressing your post, which reads `dat <- fread('data.txt'),`. That is, is this the command you're using?

Comment: Either of them imports from 01/02/1933 only.

Comment: Maybe it's looking at your data and saying, "hey, there are 7 variables per line" (separating NO and RECORD, because how would it know not to?) and therefore disregarding any lines that have fewer values. You might be able to get a better sense of what it's doing with `fread(bah, verbose=TRUE)`.

Comment: Somehow it is skipping the text without needing the skip..

Comment: Good tip. Trying it....

Comment: @Frank I have attached the verbose message. How can I force it to take line 14 as the header and rest as data?

Comment: It looks like you have **2 tabs** between `DATE` and `HEIGHT`. That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @ChiPak How did you fix it? Maybe it's not a good idea to touch the raw dataset itself? I would like to do it programmatically..

Comment: Make sure you have the same number of fields between the header and the rest of the data (I'll provide example as answer...). I'm not sure how to do this programmatically. The problem is that you'll have a mismatch between the number of fields for the header and data based on automatic detection of a delimiter.

Comment: Dropbox maybe?....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 12 lines of text, 2 lines of spaces, and then your data. But I noticed extra whitespace between `DATE` and `HEIGHT`. So make a text file like this, where your data is tab-delimited, and add **2 tabs** between `DATE` and `HEIGHT` instead of **1 tab**

```
garbage
garbage
garbage
garbage
garbage
garbage
garbage
garbage
garbage
garbage
garbage
garbage


DATE        HEIGHT  INPUT   OUTPUT  TESTMEASURE
01/01/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING MISSING
01/02/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING MISSING
```

Doing `fread(data)` gives me:

```
fread(data)
   01/01/1933 NO RECORD NO RECORD MISSING MISSING
1: 01/02/1933 NO RECORD NO RECORD MISSING MISSING
```

Removing the extra tab between `DATE` and `HEIGHT` gives me:

```
         DATE    HEIGHT     INPUT  OUTPUT TESTMEASURE
1: 01/01/1933 NO RECORD NO RECORD MISSING     MISSING
2: 01/02/1933 NO RECORD NO RECORD MISSING     MISSING
```